How to take a screenshot of a video on Flutter Web?
I'm working on a Flutter web app that uses the Media Kit Player package for video playback. I want to add functionality to take screenshots of the video at any point.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Media Kit Player's screenshot method – Works with local videos but not with web videos.
Testing the same video in Flutter mobile – Screenshot functionality works fine, so the issue seems web-specific.
Checked for CORS issues – Ensured that CORS is allowed on the video, but it still doesn't work.
Using the Screenshot package – Wrapped the video widget, but it returns a black image.

My questions are:

Is there a video player package for Flutter that works on the web and supports taking screenshots?
If I use the Flutter Video Player, how can I implement screenshot functionality myself?
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!


To take a screenshot of a video,  you can use the screenshot package:

wrap your widget in a Screenshot widget:

Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Text("This text will be captured as image"),
),


call .capture on your Screenshot controller:


    screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
        //Capture Done
        setState(() {
            _imageFile = image;
        });
    }).catchError((onError) {
        print(onError);
    });



